# Mockito- mocking database calls

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, mockito

I have tried to mock the following method with Mockito which returns user details.

It is making the actual call to the database instead of returning the mock results.

**My method-**

```
public User getUserById(String userId){
    if (userId == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("AssociateId cannot be null");
    }
    User user = new User();
    preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        connection = dbConnection.openConnection(properties, inputStream);
        query = queryReader
                .getQuery(RelationshipManagerConstants.selectUser);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(I_User.associateId, userId);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            user.setAssociateId(resultSet.getString(I_User.associateId));
            user.setAssociatePassword(resultSet
                    .getString(I_User.associatePassword));
            user.setAssociateRole(resultSet.getInt(I_User.associateRole));
            user.setAssociateIsActive(resultSet
                    .getBoolean(I_User.associateIsActive));
            user.setAssociateEmail(resultSet
                    .getString(I_User.associateEmail));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.warning("Cannot return User Details. ClassNotFoundException occured.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.warning("Cannot return User Details. SQLException occured.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.warning("Cannot return User Details. IOException occured.");
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.warning("Failed to close resultSet.");
            }
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.warning("Failed to close statement.");
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.warning("Failed to close connection.");
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

**My test-**

```
@Test
public void testGetUserById() throws Exception {
    mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    Properties mockProperties =  Mockito.mock(Properties.class);
    InputStream mockInputStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
    DBConnection mockDbConnection = Mockito.mock(DBConnection.class);
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStatement = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    ResultSet mockResultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    QueryReader mockQueryReader = Mockito.mock(QueryReader.class);


    PowerMockito.whenNew(DBConnection.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(mockDbConnection);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(QueryReader.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(mockQueryReader);


    String query = "select * from User where AssociateID=?;";
    Mockito.when(mockDbConnection.openConnection(mockProperties, mockInputStream)).thenReturn(mockConnection);
    Mockito.when(mockQueryReader.getQuery("sqlScript_selectUser.sql")).thenReturn("query");
    Mockito.when(mockConnection.prepareStatement("query")).thenReturn(mockPreparedStatement);
    Mockito.when(mockPreparedStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
    Mockito.when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(true);

    Mockito.when(mockResultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("message");
    User u=userDAO.getUserById("AB1234");
    assertEquals("EX112233", u.getAssociateId());
}
```

My test should fail as I am returning "message" However, I am asserting with "EX112233"

But It is making call to the database instead of mocking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using in-memory db to test your DAOs? This test is too overloaded by mocks and will not be easy to support..

Comment: I think you're better off writing integration tests for this method rather than unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you prepared UserDAO for test in PowerMockito [using `@PrepareForTest`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects)?

Remember that you need to prepare the class that calls `new DBConnection()` and `new QueryReader()` for those constructor stubs to have effect.

Comment: Yes. I did prepare My UserDAO

Comment: Hrm. If you're doing that, and running your test with PowerMockRunner, then I'm not sure I have any better ideas based on the code you've posted.